# Not able to call facebook feature on other activitys

Tags: android, facebook

I am working with Facebook API using Android SDk. Here am facing one problem :

If I reside in same Activity (Single Activity) I am able to use the features like "Wall Post",
"App Request" etc. But If I want those features on some other activity say third/fourth activity (upon navigation) I am not able to get access to the pages for "Wall Post" , "App request" etc.
Can anyone help me out of this ? Please tell me if I am missing something. In every activity's oncreate() method, i m using setconnection() and getID(). Than I am calling facebook features from my facebook activity by using Menus.

Below is my code :

```
    public void setConnection() {
        mContext = this;
        mFacebook = new Facebook(getResources().getString(R.string.FACEBOOK_ID_TEST));
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    }

    public boolean isSession() {
        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
        Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
        Log.d(TAG, access_token);

        if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
                mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        return mFacebook.isSessionValid();
}

    public void getID()
    {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fields", "birthday");
        try {
            mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             Log.e("Error in FaceBook Friends List","Exception = "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         if (isSession()) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
                try {
                    mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     Log.e("Error in FaceBook Friends List","Exception = "+e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         } else {
                 // no logged in, so relogin
                 Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
                 mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create new Facebook object for each activity. I recommend have a Utility class with static Facebook object which you initialize in your main activity and use this object though other activities.

E.g.

```
Class Utiltiy {
  public static Facebook mFacebook;

  public static void initialize() {
      mFacebook = new Facebook(app_id);
  }
}
```

You call Utility.initialize() in your main activity's onCreate()

and wherever you need to make Facebook API call, you can use:

Utility.mFacebook.request(....).

Hope this is helpful.